# Series converge or diverge : $\sum^\infty_{n=1}n(1+n^2)^p$ , $p\in\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

- $\sum^\infty_{n=1}n(1+n^2)^p$ , $p\in\mathbb{R}$

I tried to compare it with other known sequencies but i couldn't find the right one.

I also tried to solve it using Mathematical Induction (for p=-1) but it led me nowhere.

Any suggestions about what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\dfrac {(1+n^2)^p} {n^{2p}} = \left(1 + \dfrac 1 {n^2} \right) ^p \to 1 \ \forall p \in \Bbb R$, so you may use [the limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) to deduce that your series exhibits the same behaviour as the series $\sum n \cdot n^{2p} = \sum \dfrac 1 {n^{-(2p+1)}}$ (the [generalized harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29#p-series)), which is known to be convergent for $-(2p+1) > 1$ and divergent for $-(2p+1) \le 1$. This gives convergence for $p<-1$ and divergence for $p \ge -1$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you have been enlightening!

Answer (score 1):

Notice how $n^2+1$ is asymtopical to $n^2$. Then, your series will behave like $n^{1+2p}=\dfrac{1}{n^{-2p-1}}$. Can you compare this to a known series?

Comment: As I am a beginner, is it valid to say $\sum^\infty_{n=1}n(1+n^2)^p$  <= $\sum^\infty_{n=1}n^{2p+1}$ , $p\in\mathbb{R}$ and go on like this?

Comment: @George.K No, because your statement is actually not true. Instead, you want to prove that those two functions are asymtopically equal $\(f(x)~g(x) $ if $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)/g(x)=1\)$ and the use the limit comparison test to have the result.

Answer (score 1):

When $p>0$ the series is clearly divergent by the divergence test.

When $p <0$ you can use the integral test and the substitution $u=x^2+1$.